# Drake visualizer not connecting to display on google cloud

Tags: drake

Hi I was trying to run drake on google cloud instance,after installation
when I tried running drake visualiser ,it's showing could not connect to display.I have enabled display devices on gcloud instance.How to solve the issue?

This is for Ubuntu 18.04 gcloud instance,installed with latest drake source code.

abhi@drake-instance:~/drake$ bazel-bin/tools/drake_visualizer
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 
Could not connect to any X display.

Comment: Is the problem really specific to drake visualizer?  Can you run `xterm` successfully?